# Bandwidth of a composite signal

Tags: bandwidth

How to find bandwidth of a composite signal that can be decomposed into five sine waves with given frequencies and having all peak amplitudes same ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here it would just be the difference in frequency between the highest frequency sine wave and the lowest?

Comment: @PaulR You have more votes than either answer - might as well make yours one as well.

Comment: @DavidK: sure - consider it done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something here it would just be the difference in frequency between the highest frequency sine wave and the lowest:

```
BW = Fmax - Fmin
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Fourier Transform your signals,after that you will get the different freq components,that will consist your spectrum,your bandwidth will be the difference between the higher and the smaller (in terms of freq) components.

Answer (score -1):

The bandwidth in this case would be the maximum frequency of the five sine waves. There is no problem if you know the five frequencies a priori. However, if that information is not available, you can do a DFT to find out the frequency content and find the index upto which the frequency content is non zero. That would give you your bandwidth.